# how to convert pugi:char_t* to string?

Tags: c++, pugixml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert pugi::char_t* to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102698/how-to-convert-pugichar-t-to-string)

how can I convert pugi:char_t* type to wchar_t string?

I want to compare the result of child_value() to some utf8 string and without that convertion I cant do that.

```
for (pugi::xml_node_iterator it = words.begin(); it != words.end(); ++it)
    {
        wchar_t* wordValue = it->child("WORDVALUE").child_value();
    }
```

this assignment return error because the right side is pugi::char_t* and the left side is whar_t*

thanks

Comment: Going by the [documentation](http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/manual/dom.html#char_t), I would use `as_wide()` as the basis, but I'd also provide an overload `as_wide(wchar_t*)` which does nothing, so you can use the function for either compiler setting.

Comment: can you tell how can I use as_wide() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea. The crude version involves modifying the library, which may break stuff in the future, but let's begin with that:

We already have these two functions:

```
std::string as_utf8(const wchar_t* str);
std::wstring as_wide(const char* str);
```

We also know that `pugi::char_t` is either `char` or `wchar_t`. So all we need in order to call the conversion function on `pugi::char_t` is an overload, which you may add to your headers:

```
std::string as_utf8(const char* str) { return str; }
std::wstring as_wide(const wchar_t* str) { return str; }
```

Now you can write this:

```
pugi::char_t * mystr = get_magic_string();
std::string mystrU8 = as_utf8(mystr);
```

This will work in both compiler settings thanks to the overload, and if `pugi::char_t` is already `char`, then this will be optimized out entirely (assuming of course that the encoding was already UTF-8, and not any other 8-bit encoding!).

(You should also provide the overloads that take `std::string` and `std::wstring` arguments to support the same magic for `pugi::string_t`.)

If you worry about polluting the library, write your own wrapper:

```
std::string my_utf8(const char * str) { return str; }
std::string my_utf8(const wchar_t * str) { return as_utf8(str); }
```

Comment: Cool. If you find the answer useful, consider accepting it :-)

Comment: I dont know if you see this comment, I use your idea and use the function as-utf8(const char *) and I get the string. actully this string is some Persian string and when I compare it to same Persian word that I had saved in utf8 textfile, the comparision doesnt work? I mean they are not same

Comment: thanks.
All you need is just add the functions my_utf8 in your code and do a match like :

if (my_utf8(node.name())=="your node name") { ... }